# Video Streaming app - How can i save the video timestamp when leaving and resume it?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, video, video-streaming, spring-webflux

I am currently building a video streaming API with Spring Boot (Webflux library). I am interested to add a functionality which will save the time of the video when leaving and ask to resume the video when the user comes back to the video.

How can I do that? Do I need to save the timestamp in a db before closing the tab with a front end?

Thank you in advance for any answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to cover all cases, i.e. even when the user suddenly kills the browser window or the systems crashes etc.

In this case the safest way is to regularly take the time stamp and send it to your server, where you would indeed save it in a database most likely, and/or save it locally in browser cookies if enabled.

The HTML5 video element has a time updated event which you can listen to to get the current time - you will not want to store it every time it fires but you can choose whatever intervals work for your use case.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event

Comment: Ok thank you i will try something like that by maybe saving the timestamp all the 5 minutes to begin